# VirtualHost Gives some 404 Not Found Error on Resources Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have a wordpress site located on

/var/www/html/site

so I wanted to setup a Virtual host for Apache 2.4

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site"
      ServerName www.site.com
      <Directory "/var/www/html/site">
              Order allow,deny
              Allow from all
              Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

But while most of the resources do load, a lot of fonts and scripts are giving a Error 404 Not Found. Why is this? 
Also what can I do? Are they restricting some but not others?

EDIT: Here's Some errors we're getting.

```
GET http://52.16.22.15/site/wp-content/plugins/djd-site-post/css/display.css?ver=4.0.1 
52.16.22.15/:41 
GET http://52.16.22.15/site/wp-content/plugins/codecanyon-5299073-bugmebar-a-simple-little-notification-plugin/bugme.css?ver=1.0.4 
52.16.22.15/:46
```

As most of the site works, only some get requests are failing to get resources. I noticed it's mostly scripts and stylesheets.

This is what I have in my directory .htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
# END wtwp_security
```

There's more but it's on the level one above. But I am also reading that VirtualHost directories do not inherit .htaccess from parent directories. IS this true?

Comment: please post some of the errors. I saw you tagging the question with `.htaccess` do you have any .htaccess rule? Did you install Rewrite mod?

Comment: @LeaTano Updated question to reflect .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try adding AllowOverride All

Like this,

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/site">
              Order allow,deny
              AllowOverride All
              Allow from all
              Require all granted
</Directory>
```